# Data Underfitting Or Not?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Is the line of regression underfitting and if yes what can I do for accurate results? I have not been able to identify such things like if the line of regression is overfitting or underfitting or accurate so suggestions regarding those will also be appreciated. The File "Advertising.csv":-https://github.com/marcopeix/ISL-linear-regression/tree/master/data

```
#Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error

#reading and knowing the data
data=pd.read_csv('Advertising.csv')
#print(data.head())
#print(data.columns)
#print(data.shape)

#plotting the data
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.scatter(data['TV'],data['sales'], c='black')
plt.xlabel('Money Spent on TV ads')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.show()

#storing data into variable and shaping data
X=data['TV'].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y=data['sales'].values.reshape(-1,1)

#calling the model and fitting the model
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X,Y)

#making predictions
predictions=reg.predict(X)

#plotting the predicted data
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.scatter(data['TV'],data['sales'], c='black')
plt.plot(data['TV'],predictions, c='blue',linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('Money Spent on TV ads')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.show()

r2= r2_score(Y,predictions)
print("R2 score is: ",r2)
print("Accuracy: {:.2f}".format(reg.score(X,Y)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work out if your model is underfitting (or overfitting) you need to look at the bias of the model (the distance between the output predicted by your model and the expected output). You can't (to the best of my knowledge) do it just by looking at your code, you need to evaluate your model as well (run it).

As it's a linear regression it's likely that you're underfitting.

I'd suggest splitting your data into a training set and a testing set. You can fit your model on the training set, and see how well it performs on unseen data using the testing set. A model is underfitting if it performs miserably on both the training data as well as the testing data. It's overfitting if it performs brilliantly on the training data but less well on the testing data.

Try something along the lines of:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# This will split the data into a train set and a test set, leaving 20% (the test_size parameter) for testing
X, X_test, Y, Y_test = train_test_split(data['TV'].values.reshape(-1,1), data['sales'].values.reshape(-1,1), test_size=0.2)

# Then fit your model ...
# e.g. reg.fit(X,Y)

# Finally evaluate how well it does on the training and test data.
print("Test score " + str(reg.score(X_test, Y_test)))
print("Train score " + str(reg.score(X_test, Y_test)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I really appreciate your help. Now I know how to evaluate and determine underfitting and overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of training and testing on same data.
Split your data set into 2,3 sets (train,validation,test)
You may only need to split it in 2 (train,test) use sklearn library function train_test_split 
Train your model on training data. Then test on testing data and see if you get good result.
If model's training accuracy is very high but testing is very low then you may say it have overfit. Or if model don't even get high accuracy on train then it is underfitting.
Hope it will you. :)